# Не валидный запрос

Tags: sql-server

Всем добрый вечер.

Столкнулся с тем, что такой вот запрос не работает:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
           WHERE     table_name = 'LDR_ACCOUNT') TRUNCATE TABLE LDR_ACCOUNT


IF (NOT EXISTS (CREATE TABLE LDR_ACCOUNT(ID_EXTRACTION INT NOT NULL,
ID_ACCOUNT varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ACCOUNT varchar(255))))
```

При этом, верние 2 строчки отрабатывают, а нижние - нет. Подскажите, как правильно написать такой запрос?

Comment: `if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='LDR_ACCOUNT' and xtype='U')
    CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: А не проще дропнуть, если существует, и потом безусловно создать новую?

Comment: Так  и делал в начале) Но лид сказал, что с DELETE будет быстрее, мол, инфа удаляется, а саму таблицу не трогаем. Ну а я, в свою очередь, нашел альтернативу DELETE -> TRUNCATE

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ELSE от верхнего IF EXISTS

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
           WHERE     table_name = 'LDR_ACCOUNT') 
           TRUNCATE TABLE LDR_ACCOUNT
ELSE 
CREATE TABLE LDR_ACCOUNT(ID_EXTRACTION INT NOT NULL,
ID_ACCOUNT varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
ACCOUNT varchar(255))
```